# Inserting enum values into HashMap

Tags: java, enums, dictionary

I am doing a program in which i need to insert enum values into a HashMap. Can we really do that? I tried out it in many ways, but failed.

Can anyone please help me? Through the program I need to implement a HashMap containing 4 threadpools (whose names act as key) corresponding to which i have a ThreapoolExcecutor object.

Below given is my code :

```
public class MyThreadpoolExcecutorPgm {
    enum ThreadpoolName
    {
        DR,
        PQ,
        EVENT,
        MISCELLENEOUS;
    }
    private static String threadName;
    private static HashMap<String, ThreadPoolExecutor> threadpoolExecutorHash;

    public MyThreadpoolExcecutorPgm(String p_threadName) {
        threadName = p_threadName;

    }

    public static void fillthreadpoolExecutorHash() {
        int poolsize = 3;
        int maxpoolsize = 3;
        long keepAliveTime = 10;
        ThreadPoolExecutor tp = null;
        threadpoolExecutorHash = new HashMap<String, ThreadPoolExecutor>();

        ThreadpoolName poolName ;
        tp = new ThreadPoolExecutor(poolsize, maxpoolsize, keepAliveTime,
                TimeUnit.SECONDS, new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(5));

        threadpoolExecutorHash.put(poolName,tp);    //Here i am failing to implement currect put()


    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may want to consider using an [`EnumMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/) instead of a `HashMap` here.  `EnumMap` is much faster and more space-efficient than a `HashMap` when using enumerated values, which seems to be precisely what you're doing here.

Comment: @aioobe- The main reason for using an `EnumMap` is that it's specifically designed to be used as a map from enumerated types to some other type.  I probably should not have cited efficiency as the main reason as much as the fact that it's probably a much better tool for the job at hand.  Thanks for pointing this out; you're completely right.

Comment: I removed my comment, because I just realized what you said in your comment, too  :)  +1 on this answer.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, it's possible to have enums as keys in a Map.

You get an error because the `threadpoolExecutorHash` maps from `String`s to `ThreadPoolExecutor`s, and it fails because you're trying to insert a `String` (`poolName`) as key.

Just change from

```
threadpoolExecutorHash = new HashMap<String, ThreadPoolExecutor>();
```

to

```
threadpoolExecutorHash = new HashMap<ThreadpoolName, ThreadPoolExecutor>();
```

---

As mentioned by @templatetypedef, there is even a special Map implementation, [`EnumMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html) tailored for using enums as keys.

Comment: And if you put enum as a key in your map, it is recommended to use EnumMap (http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html) that has internal representation as an array and is efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a String as the key of your HashMap, you should be using the Enum class instead. Your code should look like this :

```
public class MyThreadpoolExcecutorPgm {
enum ThreadpoolName
{
    DR,
    PQ,
    EVENT,
    MISCELLENEOUS;
}
private static String threadName;
private static HashMap<ThreadpoolName, ThreadPoolExecutor> threadpoolExecutorHash;

public MyThreadpoolExcecutorPgm(String p_threadName) {
    threadName = p_threadName;

}

public static void fillthreadpoolExecutorHash() {
    int poolsize = 3;
    int maxpoolsize = 3;
    long keepAliveTime = 10;
    ThreadPoolExecutor tp = null;
    threadpoolExecutorHash = new HashMap<ThreadpoolName, ThreadPoolExecutor>();

    ThreadpoolName poolName ;
    tp = new ThreadPoolExecutor(poolsize, maxpoolsize, keepAliveTime,
            TimeUnit.SECONDS, new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(5));

    threadpoolExecutorHash.put(poolName,tp);    //Here i am failing to implement currect put()
}
```